# Adding mleader to AutoCAD

Tags: vba, autocad

Currently my program has a leader with mtext in it and I wanted to convert it to a multi-leader so the text is infused and it's easier and nicer to move around. So for leader it's easier.. I just add `.addleader(pointsarray, annotation, leadertype)`

But for mleader it's : `.addmleader(pointsarray, leaderlineindex as long)`

So my question is... what's **leader line index**? And where does my leader text go? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what's **leader line index**?

- an `MLeader` object is an "*object composed of an arrowhead attached to multiple splines or straight line segments*"

  so it can have multiple lines (i.e. *leader lines*), each one identified through its own index (i.e. **leader line index**)

  when you create a `Mleader` object through its `AddLeader()` method, you're setting its *first* leader line, that you *have to* identify through its index (normally *zero*, but you can specify any positive integer)

  you may very well use a literal integer:

  ```
  Set oML = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddMLeader(pointsArray, 0) '<--| set newly created leader line index to zero (or 1, or whatever positive integer)
  ```

  but it's convenient to store it in some (`Long`) variable so it can be subsequently used by such other object methods as, for example, `AddLeaderLine()` or `SetLeaderLineVertices()`

And where does my leader text go?

- you just set `MLeader` `TextString` property to wanted text

  for instance:

  ```
      Dim oML As AcadMLeader
      Dim points(0 To 14) As Double

      ' Define the leader points
      points(0) = 1: points(1) = 1: points(2) = 0
      points(3) = 1: points(4) = 2: points(5) = 0
      points(6) = 2: points(7) = 2: points(8) = 0
      points(9) = 3: points(10) = 2: points(11) = 0
      points(12) = 4: points(13) = 4: points(14) = 0

      Set oML = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddMLeader(points, 0) '<--| set the MLeader object (and assign it a leader line index of zero)

      oML.TextString = "This is Mleader Text" '<--| set its text
  ```

a thorough reading of [this AutoCAD Help page](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2015/ENU/?guid=GUID-95FD33C2-DF78-4014-933C-9AC124E6A35D) can possibly help you better understanding the issue

Answer (score 1):

Per AutoDesk knowledge base it is "Input index of the mleader cluster", whatever that is. Review [AutoDesk AddMLeader](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-991E00FE-2128-4162-9C4A-80934C4897B2-htm.html). The example in that link shows declaring i but does not set it so it defaults to 0 which means the parameter is 0.